# "Magically" avoiding segfault

Tags: c, pointers, tree, segmentation-fault, pointer-to-pointer

I wrote a small demo program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct tag_node {
    struct tag_node *left, *right, *prev;
    int value;
} node;

int main()
{
    node *root_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    root_node->value = 1;
    node **position = &root_node->right;
    *position = malloc(sizeof(node));
    (*position)->value = 2;
    (*position)->prev = root_node;
    printf("root node is %d, right node is %d\n",
        root_node->value, root_node->right->value);
    node **ptr = &(*position)->prev->prev->prev;
    printf("This is fine\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and compiled it with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 example.c -o example`.
In my opinion the program must crash at the `node **ptr = &(*position)->prev->prev->prev;` line because:

1. `*position` is the `root->right` address;
2. `(*position)->prev` is the `root` address;
3. `(*position)->prev->prev` is the `root` `previous` address, i.e., NULL;
4. `(*position)->prev->prev->prev` is NULL dereferencing, which must cause a `segfault` error.

Nevertheless the program feels great, prints "This is fine" and returns exit code 0.

Could someone please explain this black magic to me?

Comment: `node **ptr = &(*position)->prev->prev->prev;` looks meaningless and can be eliminated by the optimization.

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78022080/magically-avoiding-segfault#comment137548038_78022080) Since it doesn't have any side-effects and the result isn't used.

Comment: `root_node->prev` isn't necessarily `NULL`, it is indeterminate.

Comment: "In my opinion the program must crash" That is generally a wrong assumption. There is no rule in C standard that demands that an illformed program must do something you might call a "crash". The worst the C standard provides is so called "undefined behaviour". And as the name already tells us, the behaviour is undefined in that case. Which may satisfy your wish for a crash or just look as if nothing bad happened. You cannot rely on that.

Comment: [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```c
node **ptr = &(*position)->prev->prev->prev;
```

is meaningless and can be eliminated by the optimization.

Interestingly, adding a line

```c
printf("%p\n",(void*)ptr);
```

after the line to make the line meaningfull also didn't invoke segmentation fault.
This looks like because we can read `(*position)->prev->prev` (this means `root_node->prev`) and can calculate the address `&(*position)->prev->prev->prev` by just adding the offset of the member `prev` to the value of `(*position)->prev->prev` without actually accessing `(*position)->prev->prev->prev`.

Also note that `malloc` doesn't initialize the allocated buffer and the value of `(*position)->prev->prev` need not be `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

> `(*position)->prev->prev->prev` is NULL dereferencing, which must cause
> a segfault error.

As it is an Undefined Behavior it must not anything. UB does not have to express itself any special way. So the claim:

> In my opinion the program must crash at the node `**ptr = &(*position)->prev->prev->prev;`

is invalid.

But this time it is not an **UB**

In your code the last prev **is not being dereferenced** only the compiler is adding the offset of the `prev` member to the NULL pointer as you want its REFERENCE but not the actual value.